# Getting started with web developmemt

Tags: python, django, web-deployment, backend

I am from embedded system development field, so please forgive me if question sound naive.Recently, I got thrilled about web development and learned python. Now thinking to start learning Django for backend web development. I searched the net but couldn't found collective information about the steps involved in developing the websites.

- Django will do the backend but how much? Will it cover the whole
  backend development or I need some or deep knowledge about other
  language/framework?
- What other factors will be involved or i need to cover beside django?
- Can anyone please mention the steps from starting with django till
  the deployment of website? Backend plus frontend?

Answer (score 3):

- Django is a complete framework that will cover everything you needs to develop a website;
- Client side, using vanilla javascript or some libraries (jQuery for example) or frameworks (Angular, Ember);
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/ - It's a COMPLETE tutorial introducing to web dev with Django.

Your question is pretty basic, follow [Stack Overflow asking rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [give more effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) before asking here.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few good books to get a hands on experience with django. From these I certainly recommend [**Django by Example**](http://djangobyexample.com/) by Antonio Mele which will guide you through building of 4 production grade applications (plus the usage of a few third-party essential apps: celery, RabbitMQ, memcached, redis, solr a.o.) As of now the book is also available as a video turorial.

Other handy resource are the video tutorials made by CodingEntrepreneurs. See for example free on youtube [Try Django 1.10 - A URL Shortening Service](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEsfXFp6DpzQSEMN5PXvEWuD2gEWVngCZ). And others on their youtube channel.